# html page is not scrolling horizontally in IOS app browser

Tags: html, ios, css, scroll

My page is not scrolling horizontally in **IOS app browser**.

The same app in **android**, is working. And its working in all browsers, but when I open it in app browser on **IOS** its scrolling only vertically, not horizontally. Is there any trick to solve this problem?

This code is not working in app browser on IOS:

```
 overflow:scroll;
 overflow-x:scroll;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Comment: not really sure if this would help in that particular situation, but you can try setting cursor: pointer; to the body. It has saved me few time with iOS devices. Please let me know if this helps in your case.

Comment: @yavor.vasilev No its not worked.